# How do I allow only certain entries in a Mongoose model field?

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

I am trying to create a mongoose database of different businesses, each with a name and certain tags. I store the tags using an array of strings however, I only want to allow tags that are included in a "constants" file that I have made (named Tags.js). Is there a way that I can validate in the express.js post request for each business that the entries for tags are included with the constants? I want to make sure that tags that are not included in the constants file cannot be posted to the tags array. Looking at the mongoose documentation, it looks like the put method might potentially be a way that I could do this but I am not sure.

The business Schema

```
const businessSchema = new Schema({
  businessName = {type: String, required, true},
  tags = [{type:String]
});
```

The tags constants

```
export const DELIVERY = "DELIVERY"
export const SUBSCRIPTION = "SUBSCRIPTION"
export const VARIETY = "VARIETY"
export const BLACK_OWNED = "BLACK_OWNED"
export const FEMALE_OWNED = "FEMALE_OWNED"
export const CURBSIDE = "CURBSIDE"
export const EVENT = "EVENT"
export const ORGANIC = "ORGANIC"
```

My current Business Post route

```
router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
let newBusiness = new Business({
    ...req.body
  })

  newBusiness.validate(function(err) {
      if (err) {
          res.status(400).json({
              success: false,
              err
          })
      } else {
          newBusiness.save().then(()=>res.status(200).json({
              success: true
          }));
      }
  });
```

})

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose, when you define your shema, you can use the [enum](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators) validator.

It creates a validator that checks if the value of a string field is in a given array.

```
const businessSchema = new Schema({
  businessName = {type: String, required, true},
  tags = [{
    type:String,
    enum: ["DELIVERY", "SUBSCRIPTION", "VARIETY", "BLACK_OWNED", "FEMALE_OWNED", "CURBSIDE", "EVENT", "ORGANIC"] 
  }]
});
```